# Moq Callback is fine in first test, but same code returns null in second test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Would anyone know why, when using moq in 2 tests I have the following code:

```
var magentoChannelMock = new Mock<IMagentoChannel>();

var magentoChannelMock = new Mock<IMagentoChannel>();

magentoChannelMock.Setup(x => x.SalesOrderInvoiceCreate(It.IsAny<string>(), "2", It.IsAny<orderItemIdQty[]>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Callback<string, string, orderItemIdQty[], string, string, string>((s1, s2, x, s3, s4, s5) => invoicesSent = x);
```

I have 2 tests in a test class, when I run each individually, they run fine and the callback object "invoicesSent" contains the expected value.  But when I run both tests at the same time, the second test that is run always gets null returned as the callback.

Any idea?

```
[Test]
public void Invoice_3Line_QtyThatIsInvoicedShouldBe12()
{
    //arrange
    orderItemIdQty[] invoicesSent = null;
    var magentoChannelMock = new Mock<IMagentoChannel>();

    magentoChannelMock.Setup(x => x.SalesOrderInfo(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                      .Returns(new salesOrderEntity() { items = new salesOrderItemEntity[] { new salesOrderItemEntity() { qty_ordered = "12", item_id = "1", sku = "SKU123" } } });
    magentoChannelMock.Setup(x => x.SalesOrderInvoiceCreate(It.IsAny<string>(), "2", It.IsAny<orderItemIdQty[]>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Callback<string, string, orderItemIdQty[], string, string, string>((s1, s2, x, s3, s4, s5) => invoicesSent = x);

    TestProjIocContainer.Container().RegisterInstance( magentoChannelMock.Object);

    var magentoApiRepository = TestProjIocContainer.ResolveObjectForTesting<IMagentoApiRepository>();

    var orderLineItem = new OrderLineItem{Quantity = 4, Material = new Material{SKU = "SKU123"},ChannelLineItemReference = "123"};

    var testInvoice = new List<InvoiceLine>
        {
            new InvoiceLine(orderLineItem),
            new InvoiceLine(orderLineItem),
            new InvoiceLine(orderLineItem)
        };

    //act
    magentoApiRepository.CreateOrderInvoice("2", testInvoice);

    //assert
    Assert.AreEqual(testInvoice.Sum(x=>x.Quantity), (int)invoicesSent.Sum(x=>x.qty) );
}



[Test]
public void Invoice_1Line_Qty4()
{
    //arrange
    orderItemIdQty[] invoicesSent = null;
    var magentoChannelMock = new Mock<IMagentoChannel>();

    magentoChannelMock.Setup(x => x.SalesOrderInfo(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                      .Returns(new salesOrderEntity() { items = new salesOrderItemEntity[] { new salesOrderItemEntity() { qty_ordered = "12", item_id = "1", sku = "SKU123" } } });
    magentoChannelMock.Setup(x => x.SalesOrderInvoiceCreate(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<orderItemIdQty[]>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Callback<string, string, orderItemIdQty[], string, string, string>((s1, s2, x, s3, s4, s5) => invoicesSent = x);

    TestProjIocContainer.Container().RegisterInstance(typeof(IMagentoChannel), "", magentoChannelMock.Object, new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

    var magentoApiRepository = TestProjIocContainer.ResolveObjectForTesting<IMagentoApiRepository>();

    var orderLineItem = new OrderLineItem { Quantity = 4, Material = new Material { SKU = "SKU123" }, ChannelLineItemReference = "123" };

    var testInvoice = new List<InvoiceLine>
        {
            new InvoiceLine(orderLineItem)
        };

    //act
    magentoApiRepository.CreateOrderInvoice("1", testInvoice);

    //assert
    Assert.AreEqual(4, (int)invoicesSent.Sum(x => x.qty));
}
```

Comment: Do your tests share state? Seems like they do. You'll have to post a [MVCE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the code you posted doesn't help.

Comment: Can you share your tests?

Comment: sorry I have added the 2 tests, these are just in a test class.

Comment: I believes the problem occurs because `TestProjIocContainer.Container()...`. (Probably the tests overrides each other...)

Comment: thats just a wrapper for my unity container, i register instances of the mocks and then resolve for the object i want to test.   I will try clear all registrations first now and get back.

Comment: thanks!! that fixed it.  I don't fully get how that breaks the callback but I added a setup that resets the registrations for each test.

Comment: @NeilHosey I can help you to understand the reason of the failure if you'll add the source code of `TestProjIocContainer`